# Covariance of minimum and maximum of uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ be iid, such that each $X_i$ has the uniform distribution on the interval $(a,b)$. Calculate $Cov(\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n),\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n))$.

The task seems very hard to me. So far I calculated $E(\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n))=\frac{an+b}{n+1}$, $E(\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n))=\frac{bn+a}{n+1}$. I also found the joint density of $(\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n),\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n))$ - it is as follows:
$$f(x,y)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{n!}{\left( n-2\right) !}\frac{\left(y-x\right)^{n-2}}{\left(b-a\right)^{n}} & \text{
if }a\leq x\leq y\leq b \\ 
0 & \text{in other cases.}%
\end{array}%
\right. 
$$
So now the task is to calculate $E(\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\cdot\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n))$. How to do this effectively?

Comment: hint : calculate probability that min is in [x, x+dx] and max is in [y, y+dy] and then use double integrals

Comment: Thomas, I have obtained the density $f$ using this method. I am able to write the double integral $E(\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\cdot\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n))$, however I just can't calculate it effectively. I have written the integral as iterated integral and just can't calculte it. Can you help?

Comment: Your joint density is wrong in two respects:  first, the power on the $(b-a)$ term ... and second, why is the domain of support constrained to $0<x<y<1$, when you have defined the domain of support of the parent on $(a,b)$?

Comment: @Almostsure The integral is not that complicated. As a variable of y it is a polynomial. The integrand is a polynomial in x too. (and you keep the factorized form)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/400677/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/842264/321264

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Covariance of \[$X_{(1)}$, $X_{(n)}$\] from $\operatorname{Unif}(a,b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4110305/covariance-of-x-1-x-n-from-operatornameunifa-b)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to solve an integral like this $\int y(y-x)^{n}dy$ the more easy way is an integration by parts

$\int y(y-x)^{n}dy=\int  y d\frac{(y-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}=y\frac{(y-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}-\int \frac{(y-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}dy=$

$=y\frac{(y-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{(y-x)^{n+2}}{n+2}$

Comment: Kmitov! (1) Thanks for your remark. (2) The last fraction in your comment should be as follows: $\frac{\left( y-x\right) ^{n+2}}{\left( n+2\right) \left( n+1\right) }$.

Comment: (2) above is of course wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Given: random variable $X \sim Uniform(a,b)$ with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

where I am assuming, without loss of generality, that $0<a<b$.

Then, the joint pdf of the sample minimum $X_1$ and the sample maximum $X_n$, say $g(x_1,x_n)$, is:

[image]

where I am using the `OrderStat` function in the *mathStatica* add-on to *Mathematica* to automate the nitty-gritties for me.

Then, $Cov(X_1, X_n)$ is simply:

[image]

All done.

**Notes**

1. The joint density $g(x_1,x_n)$ is different to that you have obtained manually ... note the power on the $(b-a)$ term.
2. As disclosure, I should perhaps add  that I am one of the authors of the software used above.

Comment: Wolfies, thanks for pointing my mistake. I've edited the density.

Comment: The complete solution, with the nitty-gritties ;-) is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677504/double-integral-over-a-triangle