Computing MSE of a linear combination of order statistics
Let $X_1 , \dots , X_n$ be IID Uniform$(\theta, 2\theta)$ with $\theta>0$. Consider estimators for $\theta$ of the form:
\begin{equation}
Z_a = aX_{(1)} + \frac{1}{2}(1-a)X_{(n)}
\end{equation}
where $X_{(i)}$ is the $i$th order statistic.
I'm tasked to find an expression for $MSE(Z_a)$.
First I know we can write $MSE(Z_a) = Var(Z_a) + Bias(Z_a)^2$.
Using the pdf of order statistics, I've computed $E(X_{(1)}) = \frac{\theta(n+2)}{n+1}$, $E(X_{(n)}) = \frac{\theta(2n+1)}{n+1}$.
This gives me $E(Z_a) = a \frac{\theta(n+2)}{n+1} + \frac{1}{2}(1-a) \frac{\theta(2n+1)}{n+1} = \frac{3a\theta + 2n\theta + \theta}{2(n+1)}$.
Thus $Bias(Z_a) = \frac{3a\theta + 2n\theta + \theta}{2(n+1)} - \theta = \frac{\theta(3a-1)}{2(n+1)}$ and $Bias(Z_a)^2 = \frac{\theta^2 (3a-1)^2}{4(n+1)^2}$ (so $Z_{\frac{1}{3}}$ is the only unbiased estimator of this form).
My trouble starts when computing $Var(Z_a)$.
I know $Var(Z_a) = a^2 Var(X_{(1)}) + \frac{(1-a)^2}{4} Var(X_{(n)}) + \frac{a(1-a)}{2}Cov(X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$
I've spent over an hour computing $E(X_{(1)}^2)$, $E(X_{(n)}^2)$, and $E[X_{(1)}X_{(n)}]$ (using joint pdf of $X_{(1)}$, $X_{(n)}$) and I'm left with an expression for $Var(Z_a)$ that's about three lines long and cannot be reduced further.
This problem was assigned as preparation for a midterm and I can't help but think I'm doing something wrong if the solution takes this long and is this messy.
Are there any tricks/shortcuts I'm missing to make this computation quicker, or is the long way the only way to do it?

Have you used the connection between the order statistics of uniforms and the Beta distribution?

No need to use the joint pdf for the variances; only use it for the covariance. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4104115/321264 and its linked posts.

As mentioned in the comments, since $Y_i = X_i/{2\theta}\sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$ for $1\leq i\leq n$, it follows that
$
Y_{(k)} \sim\text{Beta}(k, n-k+1)
$
where in general $W\sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$ if $W$ has the density
$$
f_{W}(x)= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}\quad (0<x<1).
$$
For the question we will need the fact that  $$EW=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$$ and
$$
\text{Var}W=\frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta +1)}
$$
which can be proven using the characterization of the beta as ratios of waiting times. More details can be found on the wiki page. In particular, returning to the question
$$
EX_{(1)} = 2\theta EY_{(1)} = \frac{2\theta}{n+1}
$$
while
$$
EX_{(n)} = 2\theta EY_{(n)} = \frac{2n\theta}{n+1}.
$$
Next
$$\text{Var}X_{(1)} = 4\theta^2\text{Var}(Y_{(1)}) = \frac{ 4n\theta^2}{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}$$
and $\text{Var}X_{(n)}$ can be computed similarly using the formula for the variance of a beta function.

Rather, $(X_i-\theta)/\theta$ is standard uniform.

@StubbornAtom thanks for the correction. Somehow my brain read $$Uniform(\theta, 2\theta)$$ as $$Uniform(0, 2\theta)$$ when answering the question
