# Product of $\min$ and $\max$ of $n$ i.i.d. random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

> Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be i.i.d. continuous uniform random variables on $\left[\vartheta-\frac{1}{2},\vartheta+\frac{1}{2}\right]$ for some $\vartheta \in \mathbb R$.

I am trying to solve $\mathbb E[(T-\vartheta)^2]$ where $T(X) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\min_{1 \le i \le n} X_i + \max_{1 \le i \le n} X_i\right)$ or simplify it such that it becomes clear that it is independent of $\vartheta$.

I have tried to approach this by a variety of conversion but always end up with a term that involes $\mathbb E\left[\left(\min_{1 \le i \le n} X_i\right)\left(\max_{1 \le i \le n} X_i\right)\right]$.

I can't find a way to actually calculate it. Do you have a hint or another way of approaching the task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform a suitable location transformation on the data:  define $$Y_i = X_i - \theta,$$ consequently $$Y_i \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(-1/2, 1/2),$$ and $$Y_{(1)} = \min_i Y_i = \min_i X_i - \theta = X_{(1)} - \theta, \\ Y_{(n)} = \max_i Y_i = \max_i X_i - \theta = X_{(n)} - \theta.$$  Thus $$(T - \theta)^2 = \left(\frac{X_{(1)} + X_{(n)}}{2} - \theta \right)^2 = \left(\frac{Y_{(1)} + Y_{(n)} + 2\theta}{2} - \theta \right)^2 = \frac{(Y_{(1)} + Y_{(n)})^2}{4},$$ and since $Y_i$ is free of $\theta$, so is the expectation.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, your expression will always involve $\max \min$. You may want to check for [order statistics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).

And for uniform distribution on $[0,1]$

$$U_{(k)}\sim \operatorname{Beta}(k,n+1-k)$$

And [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400677/covariance-of-order-statistics-uniform-case) discuss about calculation of $\mathbb E[U_{(k)} U_{(j)}]$